# AWS Policy to start-instance via AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to attach a AWS policy to a IAM user that only makes it possible to use AWS CLI for `start-instance` and `stop-instance` on EC2.

It works by using the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy, but I want to restrict it.

I used a mix of `startInstances`, `stopInstances`, `describeInstances`, ... but it didn't work.

I am using `aws ec2 start-instance --instance-ids i-123`.

Any ideas?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": ["cloudwatch:*","ec2:Describe*"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": ["ec2:StartInstances","ec2:StopInstances"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1b:123412341234:instance/i-123412341234"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should include a sanitized version of your IAM policy. And what error message are you seeing (a better description than "it didn't work")?

Comment: The error message was encrypted.

Comment: AWS error responses (codes and messages) aren't encrypted (beyond being sent you over HTTPS). Are you encrypting (and cannot decrypt) the response somehow? Also, without a policy and an actual error, we really can't help diagnose this properly.

Comment: You can decode the error message using [decode-authorization-message — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html),

Answer (score 0):

The policy to **allow** the IAM user to "ec2:StartInstances" and "ec2:StopInstances" would look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": ["cloudwatch:*","ec2:Describe*"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": ["ec2:StartInstances","ec2:StopInstances"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

See how the cloudwatch and ec2:Describe actions are in a separate statement, they used to only support a **Resource** of **"*"**. You can see AWS does the same thing, separate the EC2 **Actions** from the Describe and Tagging: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:DeleteTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello. I used the above code and it still does not work. It says:
"An error occured (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the StopInstance operation. You are not authorized to perform this action".

Comment: @Steve, any chance you could sponsor me a glance at your code? Kindly [edit] the question, can you?

Comment: I am using `aws ec2 start-instance --instance-ids i-123`. Does this help?

Comment: I added the policy I tested to my initial question above.